# Acumatica - PXGridColumn property for Text box on Processing page

Tags: acumatica

How to add an input field on processing page grid column.
There is option to add Type in PXGridColumn property but it does not have any value for text box and then the column result as readonly on UI,
Where as the added column should take the input,
Example - Need to process all the Production Order and set its status

Comment: Likely the whole DataView as been disabled with AllowUpdate=False. You need to revert that and disable each column except your target. Consider changing your design, almost all Processing Screen are read-only for good reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Put the field you want to set on the header instead of the detail lines, and then set all the status' based on the header value. Like Hugues said, the entire grid is probably disabled for a reason.